# KeyDown code working for all forms but one

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I'm disabling the F11 key on my Access forms using the KeyDown event, which is straightforward enough using this code:

```
Private Sub Form_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer) 
If KeyCode = vbKeyF11 Then KeyCode = 0 
End Sub
```

F11 no longer does anything on all the forms for which I've implemented this code except one, namely the main input form.  Said form is the most complex in the application so I thought something else in the form's code was conflicting.  However, I tried commenting out everything else and the KeyDown code still isn't working.

I've also confirmed that Key Preview is set to Yes, and successfully tested other actions on `vbKeyF11`, e.g. `If KeyCode = vbKeyF11 Then MsgBox "pressed F11"`

Comment: are you pressibg the key in a control?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav yeah, but I have Key Preview set to Yes which should take care of it.  And I can get it to display a msgbox, so the form is receiving the key.

Comment: Under Access Options > Current Database uncheck "Use Access Special Keys".

Comment: @tlemaster that option was giving me trouble by no longer working if I made changes to the app after doing that. Figured out that was why just now...

Comment: @Rominus can we bring this back to simplicity and remove all code form that form aside from the keypress code.  Then update your question with only code pertinent to the keypress side of things.

Comment: @Newd revision done

Answer (score 0):

make sure [Event Procedure] is existed on your FORM's Property Sheet - Event
or make Compile Database to find errors then Compact and Repair Database

[Click Here to see picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwLuN.png)